# Run Custom PowerShell script under a specific ServicePrincipal Account context via ADF or?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, azure-service-principal

I have a specific power-shell script which i can run myself using spn credentials myself via powershell. This script is used to get access-token to then be used within the AAS model to update the token, so that it can then process the tabular AAS Model. This all works fine when i run it myself using spn clientid/clientsecret.

But I have to automate the same to execute unattended, when a proceeding ADF job finishes. For automated unattended execution in prod, I will not have access to the CLientSecret value of the app registration. Is their a way to do this, so that it(ADF job or otherwise) can run a power-shell script directly under the SPN context without me manually trying to store the secret and then login within the powershell script like so. ?

```
param( 
    [string] $ClientID = "a90-blah-client-id-3672",
    [String] $ClientSecret = "xnQ05~blah~blah"
)
###### Login using supplied Automation Credential details(spn clientid & key(needs to be secure string)
$AutomationCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientID,$ClientSecret)

############# Connect to Azure session using the ServicePrincipal , Automation Credential ,  SubscriptionID & TenantID
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $AutomationCredential -SubscriptionId "$SubscriptionID" -Tenant $TenantID
 Get-AzContext
```

can the $AutomationCredential  instead the the current context , which is kicked off under the ServicePrincipal Credentials ? This way there will be no need to read the secrets as its current context is already authenticated ?
The secret is reset automatically every month via some other magic code elsewhere, so has to be read at runtime before processing the tabular model.

PS->Am new to ADF world

Thanks in advance.

Everything i tried so far resulted in me knowing the secret of the spn for the script to work , which is not what i am after for a Non-interactive execution. As in production i am not meant to be knowing the secret.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ADF has no out of the box feature/activity to execute powershell script.

You can leverage Azure automation and managed identity aspect :

```
 Connect-AzAccount -Identity
```

A github repo for powershell for AAS refresh :
https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/AzureAutomation/ProcessAzureAS.ps1

And then you can leverage web hook activity to trigger the Azure automation at the end of the ADF pipeline

MSFT doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks?tabs=portal